# How to use HotString with variable & wildcard?

Tags: autohotkey

In Onenote, let's say I want to write x^y (x to power of y), I would need to enter Equ mode (by keyboard shortcut) , type x^y , hit Space, then exit equ mode

So, I figure it could be something like this :

```
::(wild_card)^(wild_card)::  
Send, (Shortcut for equ mode)  
Send, variable1  
Send, ^
Send, variable2  
Send, space  
Send, (Shortcut for equ mode)
```

How do I actually achieve this ?

Alternatively, the same purpose could be formulated by doing,
- monitor word separated by Ending chars
- detect if `^` is in those word
- Send (Shortcut) , then the word, then space, then (Shortcut).
Is this more doable ?

Comment: Have a look at [RegEx Powered Dynamic Hotstrings](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/15015-regex-powered-dynamic-hotstrings/). You'll need to do just a few adjustments to the `percent` example to get what you want. Of course, you should check if OneNote is active before triggering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks MCL,

Here is the code for auto convert x_y and x^y into their mathematical representation in onenote

```
#Include DynamicHotstrings.ahk
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Framework::CFrame
hotstrings("(\w+\_\w+) ","dowork")
hotstrings("(\w+\^\w+) ","dowork")

dowork:
    Send, {LAlt Down}{=}{LAlt Up}
    SendRaw, %$1%
    Send,  {Space}
    Send, {LAlt Down}{=}{LAlt Up}
    Send,  {Space}
    Return
```

Better yet , you can modify the DynamicHotstrings.ahk so it will ignore auto convert when we are already in equation mode:

```
hotstrings(k, a = "")
{
    CoordMode,Pixel,Screen
    PixelGetColor, color, 455, 1
    if (color =  0xD7337F)
        return
      ....
```

Comment: Good work, a few notes, though: 1) I believe, escaping the underscore (**\\_**) in regex is not necessary. 2) Checking a pixel by coordinates for the sake of identifying a window (state) is almost always unreliable. If it's an own window, try identifying it. If it's just a control, work with the `Control...` commands. 3) `#IfWin` will most likely not apply to the `hotstrings()` function. You will have to modify the function for that, too by checking `IfWinActive, ...`.